# How to make MarkerClusterGroup cluster polygons

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polygon, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to show clusters using markerclustergroups with Polygons. Right now the polygons are shown but the clusters aren't. I have been trying to use center of mass for the polygons because it seems like markerclustergroup doesn't like polygons but that doesn't really work since the animation of markerclustergroup will be set on the centroids and not the actual polygon.

My polygons all vary in amount of coordinates. Some have +10 sets others have 3.
How would I use markerclustergroup for polygons?

Below my code can be seen:

```
        // Create variable to hold map element, give initial settings to map
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [23.70489, 43.90137],
            zoom: 5
        });

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        }).addTo(map);

        var ojStyle = {
            "color": "#ff7800",
            "weight": 5,
            "opacity": 0.65
        };
        // Hardcoded polygons as GeoJSON
        var polygons = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [37.99896240234376, 21.55017532555692],
                            [39.39422607421876, 21.476073444092435],
                            [38.88336181640626, 22.56582956966297],
                            [38.023681640625, 22.611475436593366],
                            [37.43591308593751, 21.99908185836153],
                            [37.28485107421876, 21.624239377938288],
                            [37.28485107421876, 21.624239377938288],
                            [37.99896240234376, 21.55017532555692]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [38.50708007812501, 21.453068633086783],
                            [39.20745849609376, 21.37124437061832],
                            [39.10858154296876, 20.876776727727016],
                            [38.80920410156251, 20.912700155617568],
                            [38.49884033203126, 20.94604992010052],
                            [38.50708007812501, 21.453068633086783]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [50.57830810546875, 25.980268007469803],
                            [50.77606201171876, 25.956809920555312],
                            [50.780181884765625, 25.69970044378398],
                            [50.56457519531251, 25.822144306879686],
                            [50.56182861328126, 25.945696562830516],
                            [50.57830810546875, 25.980268007469803]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [54.37408447265626, 24.51963836811676],
                            [54.29443359375001, 24.40963901896311],
                            [54.25872802734375, 24.449649897759667],
                            [54.32739257812501, 24.539627918861232],
                            [54.37133789062501, 24.559614286039903],
                            [54.37408447265626, 24.51963836811676]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [54.40155029296876, 24.463400705082282],
                            [54.41940307617188, 24.489648077028683],
                            [54.45785522460938, 24.462150693715266],
                            [54.43450927734376, 24.43839812102505],
                            [54.40155029296876, 24.463400705082282]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
        var polygonArray = []
        for (i = 0; i < polygons.features.length; i++) {
            polygonArray.push(polygons.features[i]);
        }

        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);
        var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(polygonArray);
        markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
        map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
```

http://js.do/code/165930 - Shows how clustering doesn't work for the polygons

I am looking for a solution like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/237/

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197882/is-it-possible-to-cluster-polygons-in-leaflet

Comment: @ghybs I actually saw your solution at http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/237/ and tried to reproduce your logic into my code. But couldn't get the rectangleclulsterable to work with my polygons.
I got a bit lost in the adding a getter and setter into the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it very much like in this GIS post: [Is it possible to cluster polygons in Leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197882/is-it-possible-to-cluster-polygons-in-leaflet)

```js
// Compute a polygon "center", use your favourite algorithm (centroid, etc.)
L.Polygon.addInitHook(function() {
  this._latlng = this._bounds.getCenter();
});

// Provide getLatLng and setLatLng methods for
// Leaflet.markercluster to be able to cluster polygons.
L.Polygon.include({
  getLatLng: function() {
    return this._latlng;
  },
  setLatLng: function() {} // Dummy method.
});
```

Updated live example: http://js.do/code/166021

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your snippet and comments made it very easily understandable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. For Angular 2+ is also it working :)